# UICollectionView + Firestore - Slow load

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

I want to display some data from Firestore, at this time there is only **3** documents with 3 fields.

**Here is my loadData function which is called in `viewDidLoad()`:**

```
    func loadDevices() {
        //clear devices array
        self.devices.removeAll()

        //get user's devices
        db.collection("devices").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: "{USER_ID}")
            .getDocuments() { (snap, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting devices: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for deviceItem in snap!.documents {
                        let data = deviceItem.data()
                        let device = Device(data: data)
                        self.devices.append(device)

                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

//                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
//                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

It takes about 2s to load 3 records from Firestore.
If I test it with hardcoded array:

```
   func loadDevices() {
      devices.append(Device(id: "1", room: "test", userId: "dddd"))
      devices.append(Device(id: "2", room: "test2", userId: "dddd2"))
      devices.append(Device(id: "3", room: "test3", userId: "dddd3"))
   }
```

It loads instantly.
**Is there something wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently nothing wrong with you code, however it is important to note that Firestore operations will take significant longer times than adding mocked data to you devices list, the reason for that is that your app is waiting for the promise to be fulfilled and the results of the query to arrive asynchronously to then proceed with its operations, which takes some time.

2 seconds are indeed longer that you would expect, and that may be caused to latency issues caused by the physical distance between you and your firestore instance. As you can see on the [Best Practices for Firestore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices), you should consider having a closer instance to where you are located in order to reduce latency and increase performance.

The good news is that the problem is not in your data complexity or amount of data, so if the number of records increase, and since firestore queries are very fast, the amount of time to fetch data should not vary to a significant longer period.

Comment: @kironet did the answer I provided you helped in any way?